# Export environment variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I have a simple Makefile:

```
app : app.cpp
      g++ -c app.cpp -o app
```

but my application demands that `var` environment variable is set (var := "/etc/file.cfg"), how to do this in Makefile? I mean, how to make it that after I ran command `make Makefile` I wold be able to do this:

`mazix@computer:~/Desktop/ echo $(var)` and I will be able to see "/etc/file.cfg" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A process can't set an environment variable in its parent process; that's just how UNIX works.

You can create a small script which sets the variable and runs the program. If the contents of the script are somewhat variable you could write your Makefile to generate the script for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
export my_var=12345_mazix
./app
```

Alternately, your Makefile could display a string meant to be copied and pasted into your `~/.profile` file, consisting of the command or commands to set those environment variables:

```
export my_var=12345_mazix
```

Comment: ok but how to write such script? this doesn't work: `#!/usr/bin/env python import os os.environ['my_var'] = '12345_mazix'`

Comment: No. You can't write a script to change the parent environment either! You can write a script to set the environment variable and then launch the program; see my edit.